# moving sprite animation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

i have a cocos2d world, and a sprite/body that is moving fast .
when contact occur i am calling animation function.
The problem is , that when the animation is running in the current sprite position, the sprite was already gone to another place so animation is not in right place:

how would i run this animation function to follow my sprite ?

code:

```
-(void)animation:(NSString *)animation
{

    NSLog(@"check:%@",animation);


    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist",animation]];
    sprite = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_00000.png",animation]]; //take the corrdinates of this picture from the plist

    sprite.position=boy.position;
    //sprite.position=ccp(160,175);

    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet = [ CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",animation]];
    [spriteSheet addChild:sprite]; //add this coordinates from the spritesheet to the screen
    [self addChild:spriteSheet];


    NSString *Path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
    NSString *animPath = [Path stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", animation]];
    NSDictionary *animSpriteCoords = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: animPath];
    NSDictionary *animFramesData = [animSpriteCoords objectForKey:@"frames"];
    int b=0;
    int a=0;
    NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
    for(int i = 1; i < [animFramesData count]; i++) 

    {
        a=a+1;
        if(a==10)
        {
            b=b+1;
            a=0;
        }


        CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_000%0i%1i.png",animation,b,a]];   //[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eye_blinking_0000%1d.png",i]
        [animFrames addObject:frame];
    }


    //CCAnimation *dollAnimation = [CCAnimation animation];
    CCAnimation* dollAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:animFrames delay:0.1f];
    //CCAnimation *dollAnimation = [CCAnimation animationWithName:@"dance" animationWithFrames:animFrames];
    //[dollAnimation setDelay:0.1f];
    CCAnimate * Action = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:dollAnimation];
    id call=[CCCallFunc actionWithTarget:self selector:@selector(finishAnimation)];
    id sequence=[CCSequence actions:Action,[CCHide action],call,nil];
    [sprite runAction:sequence];
}
```

thnaks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCFollow will have the animation sprite follow the boy sprite:

```
id follow = [CCFollow actionWithTarget:boy];
[sprite runAction:follow];
```

Alternative is to continuously update the animation sprite's position to that of the boy position (sprite.position = boy.position) in a scheduled update method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the sprite-boy already has a sequence of actions that one of them is that animation. so i did this: [sprite runAction:sequence];
[sprite runAction:follow]; and the animation occur but it follow to the other direction then of my boy- if it goes right animation goes left.. and it also not on the same position.. why is that ?